# In North Carolina, looking for tips to plant now for raised beds

Tags: plant-recommendations, raised-beds

I just purchased two raised cedar beds to replace some crummy plastic ones that we didn't like.

What are some flowers and vegetables that I can plant as early as March?

Comment: Green, leafy things love cool Sprng weather - spinach, lettuce, broccoli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vegetables, all you need is a planting schedule for your gardening zone. Your profile says you are in Raleigh, USA, which I believe is gardening zone 7A.  Here's a schedule I found on "[The Joy Blog](https://www.thejoyblog.net/2019/02/gardening-zone-7a-planting-calendar.html)"

[image: Planting Schedule for Zone 7A]

Which shows beets, lettuce, onions, peas, radishes, and spinach as ready to go into the ground in March.

Ornamental plants are often talked about relative to the last frost date, which for your zone averages May 4.  I can't think of many that would go in 4+ weeks before that date.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks much.